# Does 「本わさび入りねり」 translate to "true/regular wasabi in paste"?

Tags: translation, food, japanese-to-english

I tried reading this text on a wasabi package.

At first, I thought it said 「本わさび人りねり」 but that didn't make sense.
Anyways, eventually I figured it might be 「本わさび入りねり」, so I looked up what Neri means and translated the text into "true/regular wasabi in paste".

I'd like to know if it's correct as I'm still below N5 level in Japanese and Google translate says it's "book wasabi" or something, which I don't think is true.

[image: the wasabi package]

Comment: It's not 「本わさび入りねり」 but 「本わさび入り＋ねりわさび」.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 本わさび（ほんわさび）the base ingredient in a processed mix of horseradish and wasabi. This is somewhat different to the more expensive and authentic wasabi plant because it has some kind of processing to allow it to exist in tube form. It contains some real wasabi derivatives but it is often less than 50%. See [here](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/fake-wasabi-horseradish_n_561bd666e4b0082030a33959?guccounter=1) for more details.
- 入り（いり）containing
- ねり paste

Basically, it's a processed paste that is sold as a cheap alternative to wasabi, but it is a mixture of horseradish with smaller amounts of real wasabi.

Comment: Is the use of 本 in 本わさび some kind of Orwellian marketing ploy? And it seems like it would be false advertising or something... Maybe I'm just misunderstanding what I saw, but I was under the impression that 本わさび was a term used to differentiate from the horseradish products. Is it actually that insidious?

Comment: For instance, the 名称 section of the wikipedia article seems to be saying, to me, that 本わさび is indeed genuine Japanese-produced wasabi. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AF%E3%82%B5%E3%83%93

Comment: Yeah it has some wasabi in it but 本わさび入り means there is less than 50% real wasabi in the product. And let's face it, given how expensive real wasabi is, you know they will put as little as possible in it.

Comment: Yes, I can see why 本わさび入り would imply a mix... but isn't 本わさび itself just real wasabi? If we're defining that term on its own.

Comment: `本わさび（ほんわさび）a processed mix of horseradish and wasabi. This is different from the more expensive and authentic wasabi plant.` ← ん？「本わさび」は genuine Japanese wasabi であり、expensive and authentic wasabi plant のことですよね。

Comment: Even so-called 100% 本わさび is still not ‘real’ wasabi, which is why I don’t agree with calling it genuine. Terms like 本わさび入り and 生わさび入り are marketing terms invented by companies which describe various mixtures and approximations of genuine wasabi. They are misleading terms which are designed to make people think there is ‘real’ wasabi, but it isn’t so simple. So the term 本わさび doesn’t actually correspond to genuine wasabi.

Comment: It seems to me that you are ascribing some of the meaning and implications of the total expression 本わさび入り to the word 本わさび. If I put "contains real wasabi" on a package because I don't want to say "made of mostly fake wasabi" that doesn't mean the words "real wasabi" mean "fake wasabi."

Comment: I’m saying that the term 本わさび describes something which uses Japanese wasabi as an ingredient but also contains other ingredients. So calling 本わさび ‘real’ wasabi is inaccurate.

Comment: My impression is it describes the ingredient, not the overall product. 本わさび入り is what describes the product. So I disagree. The OP already accepted the answer so I'll just drop it.

Comment: I know a Japanese sushi chef who once explained all the sneaky tricks that these companies use in wasabi products. It’s by no means a simple thing to understand and the average consumer doesn’t know what’s in these products. Sometimes 本わさび doesn’t even use wasabi grown in Japan. Anyway, they go to great lengths to emphasise the ‘real’ aspect of the wasabi and disguise the details, but it’s not a simple case of 本わさひ=real wasabi. In my opinion.

Comment: I know I said I'd drop it, but I just want to confirm one last thing. If I was going to make a real/fake wasabi mixture, and I had the two plants on a table front of me, you're telling me the you would not say 本わさび and 西洋わさび to refer to the two unprocessed plants in that stage? That's your position? Your position is that the resulting mixture is what is called 本わさび?

Comment: No, I’m saying that the term 本わさび (as opposed to 山葵) is a misleading marketing term which describes an ingredient which is itself comprised of other things. It isn’t the same as ground wasabi root. That is then blended with horseradish, colourings, etc to make the final product. I’m sorry if I wasn’t clear, but that is my understanding based on what I was told and what I’ve read.

Comment: It still kind of sounds like what you described is a "yes" to my question, but I understand what your point is.

Comment: I would call the unprocessed plant 山葵, not 本わさび.

Comment: @Leebo I understand 本わさび入り to mean "containing real wasabi" (but of course when you say "containing" it suggests it also contains other things).

Answer (score 4):

The label translates to "wasabi paste containing real/true wasabi"

- 本わさび入り means "containing real/true wasabi"
- [練り]{ねり} is often used as a prefix to mean "ground X" or "X paste" (for example ねりごま ≒ tahini) and the word here is ねりわさび (even though ねり and わさび are written in different fonts)